# Screen blanking time when locked

Tags: lock-screen

On Ubuntu 20.04, the screen blanking timeout when the system is locked is only 15 seconds. This is a problem since my monitor is slow to turn on. I like to press a key to wake it up before I sit down or do some other quick thing at my desk, but the screen tends to turn off before I get around to typing my password.

Is there some way to adjust the blanking time **when locked**? Note that this is **not** the same thing as the normal screen blanking time, which determines how long it takes **before** the screen is locked automatically.